# p-part of the Brauer group of a complete intersection in char p

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complete intersection of dimension at least $3$ over a separably closed field. Is $Br(X)$ trivial?

This is true for the prime-to-p part. It seems to me that it should also be true in general but I do not know a proof.

Comment: I do not see a proof immediately.  One strategy is to use SGA 2 to try  to extend the Azumaya algebra to projective space, and then you can use the triviality of the Brauer group of projective space (proved in Manin's "Cubic Forms", among others).  Another strategy is to lift first $X$, then the Brauer class over the Witt vectors of the separably closed field.  Then some care is required to avoid finite extensions of the Witt vectors that specialize to inseparable extensions of the separably closed field.

Comment: @tzy: Can you prove the result over algebraically closed fields?

Comment: @DanielLoughran.  Over algebraically closed fields, you can lift to the Witt vectors, make whatever finite extension you like of the Witt vectors (since the residue field is algebraically closed), and thus reduce to the case of characteristic 0.  Then you can use the Lefschetz principle and the exponential sequence.

Comment: @JasonStarr: If I understand your strategy with lifting to Witt vectors correctly, I need to know that Azumaya algebras deform. How do you know that the obstruction vanishes (at least after some elementary transformation, as what de Jong has done)? Or do you use some other argument to lift the Azumaya algebra?

Comment: @tzy: Dear tzy, For the prime-to-$p$ part of the Brauer group, existence of lifts over the Witt vectors follow from the Proper Base Change Theorem in etale cohomology; interpret the Brauer group as the cohomological Brauer group.  For the $p$-part, perhaps there is a Proper Base Change Theorem for the fppf site -- I need to think about this further.  Anyway, I am sorry for not have a better answer to this (and to other questions).